# WYSIWYG editor for .NET, disabled formatting using keyboard shortcut

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor as a Rich Text editor field in my .NET application.

The problem is my client don't want users to format text with keyboard shortcuts, users could only format with menu buttons in the Rich Text editor.

Do you know how to disable keyboard formatting with CKEditor and with WYSIWYG in general?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you use latest CKEditor, you got to purge `keystrokeHandler`:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    evt.editor.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes = [];
} );
```

See: [config.keystrokes](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-keystrokes) and [editor.setKeystroke](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke).